# solve Crash Log in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, crash-reports

I have an app of sending free text MSG ..
While i select a contact i got my application crash and from crash log i didn't get solution of it .. 
Can any one tell me how to solve crash log with proper stapes ..

**Here is my Crash Log :**

```
Incident Identifier: A8E3BBD6-CD0D-45C8-8134-65EF03CBFF5E
CrashReporter Key:   64c47e02a46dcc17a25718b8b3d9f579f535b545
Hardware Model:      iPhone2,1
Process:          [6703]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/9055F800-A876-4D5E-B1CD-202BC6F80BDB/.app/
Identifier:      
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-11-24 13:27:16.113 +0530
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.1 (8B117)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x656a6277
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000027d8 objc_msgSend + 16
1   CoreFoundation                  0x000042ae CFRetain + 62
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0002832a +[__NSArrayI __new::] + 54
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00028152 -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:] + 122
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00027ef4 +[NSArray arrayWithObjects:] + 356
5                           0x00033fcc 0x1000 + 208844
6                           0x00033f46 0x1000 + 208710
7   UIKit                           0x0022fb26 -[UISearchDisplayController searchBar:textDidChange:] + 78
8   UIKit                           0x001f48aa -[UISearchBar(UISearchBarStatic) _searchFieldEditingChanged] + 106
9   CoreFoundation                  0x00047712 -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 18
10  UIKit                           0x0010dfa0 -[UIApplication sendAction:fromSender:toTarget:forEvent:] + 76
11  UIKit                           0x00137c00 -[UIControl(Deprecated) sendAction:toTarget:forEvent:] + 28
12  UIKit                           0x000ab930 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEventMask:withEvent:] + 352
13  UIKit                           0x000dd888 -[UITextField fieldEditorDidChange:] + 188
14  UIKit                           0x000dd6c0 -[UIFieldEditor webViewDidChange:] + 48
15  Foundation                      0x000146ac _nsnote_callback + 136
16  CoreFoundation                  0x0002670c __CFXNotificationPost_old + 396
17  CoreFoundation                  0x000263ac _CFXNotificationPostNotification + 112
18  Foundation                      0x00003db0 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 64
19  CoreFoundation                  0x0004b42c __invoking___ + 60
20  CoreFoundation                  0x0004b2fe -[NSInvocation invoke] + 102
21  WebCore                         0x00049816 SendMessage(NSInvocation*) + 10
22  WebCore                         0x00057dc0 SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation*) + 700
23  WebCore                         0x000617f4 WebThreadPostNotification + 88
24  WebKit                          0x0001347c WebEditorClient::respondToChangedContents() + 24
25  WebCore                         0x0026d8ce WebCore::Editor::respondToChangedContents(WebCore::VisibleSelection const&) + 98
26  WebCore                         0x0026db34 WebCore::Editor::appliedEditing(WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::EditCommand>) + 204
27  WebCore                         0x004e852a WebCore::TypingCommand::insertTextRunWithoutNewlines(WebCore::String const&, bool) + 258
28  WebCore                         0x004e8606 WebCore::TypingCommand::insertText(WebCore::String const&, bool) + 134
29  WebCore                         0x004e6c7a WebCore::TypingCommand::doApply() + 126
30  WebCore                         0x0026af2e WebCore::EditCommand::apply() + 86
31  WebCore                         0x0026af8c WebCore::applyCommand(WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::EditCommand>) + 4
32  WebCore                         0x004e8ba6 WebCore::TypingCommand::insertText(WebCore::Document*, WebCore::String const&, WebCore::VisibleSelection const&, bool, bool) + 526
33  WebCore                         0x0027020a WebCore::Editor::insertTextWithoutSendingTextEvent(WebCore::String const&, bool, WebCore::Event*) + 210
34  WebCore                         0x002751e0 WebCore::EventHandler::defaultTextInputEventHandler(WebCore::TextEvent*) + 76
35  WebCore                         0x00066a86 WebCore::Node::defaultEventHandler(WebCore::Event*) + 342
36  WebCore                         0x000666e2 WebCore::Node::dispatchGenericEvent(WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::Event>) + 578
37  WebCore                         0x00066440 WebCore::Node::dispatchEvent(WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::Event>) + 144
38  WebCore                         0x00164232 WebCore::EventTarget::dispatchEvent(WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::Event>, int&) + 54
39  WebCore                         0x0027535c WebCore::EventHandler::handleTextInputEvent(WebCore::String const&, WebCore::Event*, bool, bool) + 43  WebCore                           0x004ee42c -[WAKResponder tryToPerform:with:] + 40
44  WebKit                          0x000122ac -[WebView(WebViewEditingActions) _performResponderOperation:with:] + 76
45  WebKit                          0x00012254 -[WebView(WebViewEditingActions) insertText:] + 16
46  UIKit                           0x00100f46 -[UIWebDocumentView insertText:] + 26
47  UIKit                           0x0010076c -[UIKeyboardImpl addInputString:fromVariantK
ey:] + 2504
48  UIKit                           0x000ffd80 -[UIKeyboardImpl handleStringInput:fromVariantKey:] + 128
49  UIKit                           0x000fec0c -[UIKeyboardImpl handleKeyEvent:] + 1292
50  UIKit                           0x000fe6ec -[UIApplication _handleKeyEvent:] + 28
51  UIKit                           0x000fe6be -[UIResponder(Internal) _handleKeyEvent:] + 22
52  UIKit                           0x000fe6be -[UIResponder(Internal) _handleKeyEvent:] + 22
53  UIKit                           0x000fe6be -[UIResponder(Internal) _handleKeyEvent:] + 22
54  UIKit                           0x000fe6be -[UIResponder(Internal) _handleKeyEvent:] + 22
55  UIKit                           0x000fe6be -[UIResponder(Internal) _handleKeyEvent:] + 22
56  UIKit                           0x000fe6be -[UIResponder(Internal) _handleKeyEvent:] + 22
57  UIKit                           0x000fe694 -[UIApplication handleKeyEvent:] + 40
58  UIKit                           0x000fe5ae -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar sendStringAction:forKey:] + 394
59  UIKit                           0x000fc2e4 -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar touchUp:] + 1656
60  UIKit                           0x000fbbe0 -[UIKeyboardLayout touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 296
61  UIKit                           0x00062dd6 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 362
62  UIKit                           0x00062750 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 256
63  UIKit                           0x0005d9f8 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 292
64  UIKit                           0x0005d330 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5104
65  GraphicsServices                0x00005044 PurpleEventCallback + 660
66  CoreFoundation                  0x00034cdc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
67  CoreFoundation                  0x00034ca0 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 160
68  CoreFoundation                  0x00027566 __CFRunLoopRun + 514
69  CoreFoundation                  0x00027270 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
70  CoreFoundation                  0x00027178 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
71  GraphicsServices                0x000045ec GSEventRunModal + 108
72  GraphicsServices                0x00004698 GSEventRun + 56
73  UIKit                           0x0000411c -[UIApplication _run] + 396
74  UIKit                           0x00002128 UIApplicationMain + 664
75                          0x0000265a 0x1000 + 5722
76   0x1000 + 5668

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0002d330 kevent + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000d6b6c _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 88
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000d65bc _dispatch_queue_invoke + 96
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000d675c _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 120
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a67a _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00073190 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007b19c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a790 _pthread_wqthread + 536
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00073190 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00000cf4 semaphore_wait_signal_trap + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0002e4ee semaphore_wait_signal + 2
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00002ae4 pthread_mutex_lock + 248
3   WebCore                         0x00002620 _WebTryThreadLock(bool) + 140
4   WebCore                         0x00002566 WebRunLoopLock(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 18
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00030236 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 10
6   CoreFoundation                  0x000300aa __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 406
7   CoreFoundation                  0x000276c0 __CFRunLoopRun + 860
8   CoreFoundation                  0x00027270 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
9   CoreFoundation                  0x00027178 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
10  WebCore                         0x000024e2 RunWebThread(void*) + 362
11  libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a27e _pthread_start + 242
12  libSystem.B.dylib               0x0006f2a8 thread_start + 0

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00000c98 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00002d64 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00027c38 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000274c2 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00027270 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00027178 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   CFNetwork                       0x00069074 CFURLConnectionSendSynchronousRequest + 244
7   Foundation                      0x000aed8c +[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:] + 76
8                           0x00025ea4 0x1000 + 151204
9                           0x000296c8 0x1000 + 165576
10  Foundation                      0x0000b222 -[NSThread main] + 38
11  Foundation                      0x000042d6 __NSThread__main__ + 966
12  libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a27e _pthread_start + 242
13  libSystem.B.dylib               0x0006f2a8 thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00000c98 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00002d64 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00027c38 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000274c2 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00027270 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00027178 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   Foundation                      0x0002d686 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 206
7   Foundation                      0x0000b222 -[NSThread main] + 38
8   Foundation                      0x000042d6 __NSThread__main__ + 966
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a27e _pthread_start + 242
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x0006f2a8 thread_start + 0

Thread 6:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00025060 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0005edfc __CFSocketManager + 540
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a27e _pthread_start + 242
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0006f2a8 thread_start + 0

Thread 7:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007b19c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a790 _pthread_wqthread + 536
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00073190 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00000c98 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00002d64 mach_msg + 44
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0002591e thread_policy + 118
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00025896 pthread_setschedparam_internal + 62
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x000257d0 pthread_setschedparam + 68
5   UIKit                           0x00100ea2 InitTextChecker + 22
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0007a27e _pthread_start + 242
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x0006f2a8 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x32ca2efa    r1: 0x32ca3270      r2: 0x656a626f      r3: 0x339737c9
    r4: 0x656a626f    r5: 0x3e8055e4      r6: 0x00000005      r7: 0x2fffd824
    r8: 0x06417f18    r9: 0x2fffd7c0     r10: 0x06417f10     r11: 0x2fffd870
    ip: 0x3e7f23e4    sp: 0x2fffd80c      lr: 0x3440f2b5      pc: 0x339737d8
  cpsr: 0x20010030
```

Thanks in Advance ....

Comment: you sent a bad object to `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:]`

Comment: @bshirley: Why not write an answer instead? :-)

Comment: @Vivek2010: Just a note: telling us that the issue is "urgent" is considered impolite. It may be urgent to you, but not to us. Instead, you should try to provide more information if possible. For example, here you can clearly see that the problem is with `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:]` after entering something in the search bar. So you should be able to track the method that calls `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:]` and post it. Also, if this from an App Store version of your app you need to save your `.dSYM` directories for these builds so you can later symbolicate your crash log completely.

Comment: @DarkDust i apologize for that "URGENT" but m fed up with this crash so write this .. and let me check over there [NSArray arrayWithObjects:] first ..

Comment: Thanks a lot solve problem ..

Comment: @DarkDust - i was in a hurry, thought i'd toss it out there before i had to go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

arrayWithObjects: takes a nil terminated list of object ids. You might have forget the nil

```
myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:aDate, aValue, aString, nil];
```

Check [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)

Answer (score 3):

Without any details (like a completely symbolicated crash log and the corresponding code) this is like looking into a crystal ball: we have to guess.

From the crash log I'd say you create an array (via `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:]`) and feed it something that is not an Objective-C object. Maybe you forgot to add `nil` as the last object in the list? It's necessary so Objective-C knows where your list of objects ends.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS that means you are trying to reach a released object. Best practice is to put some break points and go step by step. I also recommend you to turn the zombies on. Product->Edit Scheme->Diagnostics and check Enable Zombie Objects.

after you do this when you crash you can see the point you crash and which method is trying to reach the released object.

Comment: The bad access doesn't necessarily stem from an released object, it also happens when you use an invalid pointer or pointer to a non-object. But checking for zombies is a good advice nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

The crash log gives you some information, which is not much, but better than nothing if you are not able to reproduce the crash yourself.

As you can see from these lines:

```
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00027ef4 +[NSArray arrayWithObjects:] + 356
5   -                               0x00033fcc 0x1000 + 208844
6   -                               0x00033f46 0x1000 + 208710
7   UIKit                           0x0022fb26 -[UISearchDisplayController searchBar:textDidChange:] + 78
```

the crash happens after a change in your searchBar, which triggers the corresponding action in your code. The action then tries to create an array and it crashes.

So, I would start checking the action that you associated to the search bar and see what happens there. You could also post it here, so that we can have a look.